# Facebook API search returns different result than web site

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api

When I search for "Ron kunitzky" in Facebook site, I instantly get a result  (and correct one). However, When I search for the same person using API user search by query, I don't get any data back (not even a single user).

For example,

Using Facebook site, I am receiving the result without any problem (Check the screenshot below).

[image: Facebook site able to get the user accurately]

But, with Apigee's Facebook API explorer, I don't receive any results. (Check the screenshot below)

[image: Not getting user result using Apigee's Facebook API explorer]

Is there anyway I can improve my search results to accurately find the correct user? Are there any other good practices for user search.

Additional info:

- Yes, the app works and searches for many other users accurately.
- Yes, I have tried and/or operators to improve the results.

Please let me know, if what other information should I provide?

Comment: i am also getting same result. did you find solution?

Comment: @banu Couldn't find any solution, yet. Will post results here, if I find something.

Comment: oh ok Zoomroo thanks. i also search.